# Wrong plot display

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am running the following code https://github.com/oxford-cs-advanced-ml-2014/practical3/blob/master/gp_demo.py on OSX and it plots the results using matplotlib.
When I run the code under Ubuntu I get the results displayed properly as it can be seen below:
[image: Matplotlib Ubuntu]

However, when I run it under OSX i get the following wrong plot:
[image: Matplotlib OSX]

I tried removing and reinstalling python but nothing worked. My current python distr. is 2.7 and I have installed it from homebrew using http://fonnesbeck.github.io/ScipySuperpack/ (in the beginning I had the macports dist and made no difference again.)

Is it a common problem?
Thank you

Comment: what is the matplotlib version under the two systems?

Comment: Ubuntu runs matplotlib 1.2.1 and macosx 1.3.1

Comment: Likely a version related issue. I use `Anaconda` distribution and kept it up to date. I got what your figure 1 shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CT Zhu, by installing Anaconda Python 2.7.6 for the current user everything was resolved.